# How to delete Record from MySQL Table with AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want to do a button with an image X and when you click the button, it removes a row in the database, only at this moment.

teste-checkbox.php

```
<style>
table {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 2px;
}

table tr:hover {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

table tr {
  text-align: left;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table td a {
  color: #0454B5;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<!--

    T A B E L A  «» C O M E Ç A

!-->
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "PAP_Login";
$password = "pap123";
$dbname = "PAP_Login";
$datatable = "registo_anomalias"; // MySQL table name
$results_per_pagina = 5; // number of results per pagina

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
<div class="um-bocado-para-cima">
<?php
if (isset($_GET["pagina"])) { $pagina  = $_GET["pagina"]; } else { $pagina=1; };
$start_from = ($pagina-1) * $results_per_pagina;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$datatable." ORDER BY deleted ASC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_pagina;
$rs_result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
  <table width="40%" border="0" class="hover">
<tr>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>ID</strong></th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Tipo de Sala</strong></th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Tipo de Avaria</strong></th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Data de Submissão</strong></th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Hora de Submissão</strong></th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Estado</strong></th>
    <th bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Editar</strong></th>
</tr>
<?php 
 while($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
?> 
<?php
$tipo_de_sala = array(
'I' => 'Informática',
'N' => 'Normal',
'O' => 'Outro'
);

$deleted = array(
'0' => 'Não arranjado',
'1' => 'Arranjado'
);
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>" >
    <td>
      <a href="AvariaDocumento.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>"><?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?></a>
    </td>
    <td><? echo strtr($row["tipo_sala"], $tipo_de_sala); ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["tipo_avaria"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["data_subm"]; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row["hora_subm"]; ?></td>
    <td>
      <!-- consultar em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5675/como-verificar-se-um-checkbox-est%C3%A1-checado-com-php -->
      <? echo strtr($row["deleted"], $deleted); ?>
    </td>
    <td></td>
<!--
    <td>
      <a href="EdicaoAvaria.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>"><img src="img/lapis.png"></a>
    </td>
-->
</tr>
<?php 
}; 
?> 
  </table>
 </div>

<div class="pagination um-bocado-para-cima">
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id_avaria) AS total FROM ".$datatable;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$total_paginas = ceil($row["total"] / $results_per_pagina); // calculate total paginas with results

if($row['total'] > 5){
    for ($i=1; $i<=$total_paginas; $i++) {  // print links for all paginas
        echo "<a href='Administrador.php?pagina=".$i."'";
        if ($i==$pagina)  echo " class='curpage'";
        echo ">".$i."</a> ";
    }
}
?>
</div>
<?php
$id = $row['id_avaria'];
?>
<!--

    T A B E L A  «» T E R M I N A

!-->
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show buttons on tr mouseover
  $(".hover tr").live("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find("td:last-child").html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="editrow(' + $(this).attr("id") + ')"><img src="img/lapis.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleterow(' + $(this).attr("id") + ') <span class="delete" id="del_<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>"><img src="img/remover.png"></span></a>');
  }); //

  // remove button on tr mouseleave
  $(".hover tr").live("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find("td:last-child").html("&nbsp;");
  });

  // TD click event
  $(".hover tr").live("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "TD") {
      alert("You can track TD click event too....Isnt it amazing !!!");
    }
  });
});
editrow = function(itemId) {
  alert("You clicked 'Edit' link with row id :" + itemId);
}
deleterow = function(itemId) {

}
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 // Delete 
 $('.delete').click(function(){
  var el = this;
  var id = this.id;
  var splitid = id.split("_");

  // Delete id
  var deleteid = splitid[1];

  // AJAX Request
  $.ajax({
   url: 'remover-dados.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { id:deleteid },
   success: function(response){

    // Removing row from HTML Table
    $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
    $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
     $(this).remove();
    });

   }
  });

 });

});
</script>
<!--
http://makitweb.com/how-to-delete-record-from-mysql-table-with-ajax/
-->
```

remover-dados.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "PAP_Login";
$password = "pap123";
$dbname = "PAP_Login";
$datatable = "registo_anomalias"; // MySQL table name

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
<?php 

$id = $_POST['id_avaria'];

// Delete record
$query = "DELETE FROM ".$datatable." WHERE id_avaria=".$id;
mysqli_query($con,$query);

echo 1;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can send all the ids in array and delete at once. `DELETE FROM TABLE where id_avaria IN (1, 2, 3)`

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You send `data: {id:deleteid}` with your ajax, but ask for `id_avaria` in your php.

Comment: You're missing a `>` on the `<a` before `<span class="delete"`.   Add an alert of console.log to your event handler `$('.delete').click(function(){ alert(".delete clicked");` to ensure it's getting there.  You don't need the `<a onclick=delete` wrapper around the span except for keyboard navigation in which case add the event handler to the `<a` not the `span`

Comment: @kerbholz the errors im getting is, when i click on button x, he do nothing.

http://prntscr.com/igqx7z

Comment: @freedomn-m you can send me the code here please?
https://hastebin.com/

Comment: https://hastebin.com/yulugikeca.bash  (missing `">`)

Comment: Please, reduce the problem. All those technologies are spanning the browser frontend to the DB backend. At what point exactly do you have problems? Extract just that part and replace the rest with mocks, then you'll have the required minimal example, but without it your question is off-topic.

Comment: @freedomn-m sorry, but dont works.

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: You've already stated that clicking on `x` does nothing.  "does nothing" needs clarification.  Have you added an alert to the js click handler? (as requested) Does it get hit? No, then there's no point looking at the PHP issues.  If it gets to the `$.ajax` code then have you added some debugging to the php handler to see what's being passed?  (as also requested) Is it hitting the handler?   just "does nothing" does not enable us to help you.

Comment: @freedomn-m 

`$(document).ready(function() {
  // show buttons on tr mouseover
  $(".hover tr").live("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find("td:last-child").html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="editrow(' + $(this).attr("id") + ')"><img src="img/lapis.png"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleterow(' + $(this).attr("id") + ')> <span class="delete" id="del_<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>"><img src="img/remover.png"></span></a>');
  }); //`

Comment: Please have a read of [tour] and [ask].  Then have a look at [mcve] specifically the *minimal* part.   Reduce your code to the bare minimum needed to cause the issue and then work up from there.  eg don't generate your page using php, use fixed html until you can get the delete to work.

Comment: Still missing the `"` - I provided a 2nd hastebin with a comment that it was missing both `"` and `>` - you've added the `>`.

Comment: Please add any extra information to the question. Posting code in commments is specially bad. Noone can read code in comments

Comment: @WebDevBooster thank you for make my english more correct.

Comment: @RiggsFolly if i send you the folders, you are able to fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you send the ID via GET method and you want to retrieve it with POST.

instead of using

```
$id = $_POST['id_avaria'];
```

use

```
$id = intval($_POST['id_avaria']);
```

also add class `delete` to a tag element

remove this function because you don't use it at all

```
deleterow = function(itemId) {

}
```

change code with invoking delete to:

```
<a class="delete"><span class="delete" data_id="<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>"><img src="img/remover.png"></span></a>
```

the last thing is to preventDefault behaviour of click and add geting `data-id` attribute

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var deleteid = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

and it would be nice also to check if this variable is passed, for example via isset() function + using prepared statements

full code:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id_avaria']);

if (!empty($_GET['id_avaria']) {
   $id = intval($_GET['id_avaria']);

   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM ".$datatable." WHERE id_avaria=?");

   $stmt->bind_param($stmt, "d", $id);
   $stmt->execute($stmt);

   if ($stmt->affected_rows($stmt) > 0) {
      echo 'deleted';
   } else {
      echo 'failed to delete';
   }

   $stmt->close();
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: No, as far as I can see you are using POST in you AJAX call, so `$_POST['id'];` is correct (as you called the parameter `data: { id:deleteid },` apart from being opening your code up to an SQL Injection vector

Comment: he does ` href="AvariaDocumento.php?id=<?php echo $row['id_avaria']; ?>"` so it looks like GET request not POST

Comment: @Robert That link is commented out I believe, so I was assuming OP was using the AJAX call at the bottom of his code

Comment: @Robert the edit button im not working at this moment, im want first put the button delete work, and after i will start work with edit.

Comment: you invoke function which is empty I mean deleteRow() add class "delete" to this element and remove "onClick" from this element and it will work.

Comment: @Robert how i do it? sorry but im am newbie with ajax.

You can post full code with your thing please? on Hastebin please?

Comment: I've edited the answer, next time try to do as less as possible to make it work then debug, if you are newbie and you want to do everything at once you'll face a lot of problems that may be hard to debug for you. Looking at the code you made a lot of mistakes. From forgetting about closing a tag, to wrong js functions to problems with PHP array keys

Answer (score 0):

In your AJAX call you call the parameter `id`

```
  // Delete id
  var deleteid = splitid[1];

  // AJAX Request
  $.ajax({
   url: 'remover-dados.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { id:deleteid },
// here    ^^

   success: function(response){

    // Removing row from HTML Table
    $(el).closest('tr').css('background','tomato');
    $(el).closest('tr').fadeOut(800, function(){ 
     $(this).remove();
    });

   }
  });
```

So your PHP should be looking for that parameter value in `$_POST['id']`

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: I would suggest turning error reporting back on. What is not working now?

Comment: the button delete is not working, he dont remove. so. he dont do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: Thank for trying to help me and im so sorry for late answer, but it dont works too.

Answer (score -4):

Try this-

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$query ="DELETE FROM $datatable  WHERE id_avaria='$id'";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: Where i add it?

Comment: // replace this with my code
$query = "DELETE FROM ".$datatable." WHERE id_avaria=".$id;
mysqli_query($con,$query);